# NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I have a problem when I am trying to run rails db:seed in the terminal. 
It's giving me the following error:

> `NoMethodError`: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Can you please help me? I have tried several things but no luck so far.

```
(1..50).each do |movie|
  response = HTTParty.get("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=8d027704c57524153a0af2b38415ac45&language=en-US&page=1")
  results = JSON.parse(response.body)

  movie = Movie.new({
    title: results["title"],
    popularity: results[0]["popularity"],
    image: results["poster_path"],
    year: results[0]["release_date"],
    genre: results[0]["genre_ids"]
    })

    movie.save
    puts "#{movie['title']} was saved."
  end
```

My schema looks like this:

```
  create_table "movies", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "image"
    t.string "year"
    t.string "genre"
    t.string "rating"
    t.string "popularity"
    t.string "video"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: _"I have tried several things"_ – the first thing I would do is launch `irb` (or `rails console`) and execute the code line by line (or expression by expression). It would reveal that `results["title"]` and `results[0]` both return `nil`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON has structure:

```
{
  "page": 1,
  "total_pages": 978,
  "total_results": 19552,
  "results": [..]
}
```

Change

```
results = JSON.parse(response.body)
```

To

```
results = JSON.parse(response.body)['results']
```

Your code is broken in other places too. Here is my suggestion:

```
res = HTTParty.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=8d027704c57524153a0af2b38415ac45&language=en-US&page=1')
results = JSON.parse(res.body)['results']

results.each do |result|
  movie = Movie.create({
    title: result['title'],
    popularity: result['popularity'],
    image: result['poster_path'],
    year: result['release_date'],
    genre: result['genre_ids']
  })

  puts "#{movie.title} was saved."
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so when I changed it, it now gives me the following error: TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer

Comment: ok, adding the [0] worked, thank you. So it seeded my list of top 50 movies but i'm not sure why it's printing the same title 50 times. Is there something wong with this line :  puts "#{movie['title']} was saved." ?

Comment: well, if I remove them, then I get an error. I'm not sure how it works then because I thought that the function each : (1..50).each do |movie|   was supposed give me info for each 50 movies.

Comment: @Em774 think about it: `(1..50).each` is a loop that will execute the given block 50 times. The API returns 20 results per page / request. That gives  50 × 20 = 1,000 movies.

Comment: @DanilSperansky thank you very much for the answer. It does indeed work. I do understand that [0] is retrieving the first item in results all the time, which is why I thought adding the loop (1..50) would do the trick and now I'm thinking of it, it doesn't make sense. Thank you for enlightening me.